# VBA: How to wait for Pop-up windows using IE

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, automation

Generally, what is the easiest way to wait for a pop-up window in VBA using the IE automation? I wrote a program with the help of this community, which has been very informative, every time that I hit a roadblock in my code. Thank you, graciously.

Situation:

I create a program that interacts with IE. It's an automation process that handles data based on the functionality of the site. In the automation process, when I click on a link, it opens a pop-up window. Here is where the problems being. Sometimes, the pop-window takes anywhere between 5 seconds to 30 seconds to load. However, I am unable to determine the length of time that it takes for the pop-window to load, nor does the program, which crashes every time it reaches outside the scope of the waiting period I set it for in the program.

Everything else works perfectly, except for this small little delete that is the ultimate death of my program and sends it spiraling downhill.

The pop-window has to load first before I am able to assign the popWindow (IE) object.

```
 Dim popWindow As InternetExplorer 
 Set popWindow = oGetIEWindowFromTitle("Site Name")
 Set deviceWindow = popWindow.Document
```

```
Function oGetIEWindowFromTitle(sTitle As String, _
                               Optional bCaseSensitive As Boolean = False, _
                               Optional bExact As Boolean = False) As Shdocvw.InternetExplorer

    Dim objShellWindows As New Shdocvw.ShellWindows
    Dim found As Boolean
    Dim startTime As Single

    found = False
    'Loop through shell windows
    For Each oGetIEWindowFromTitle In objShellWindows
        found = oGetIEWindowFromTitleHandler(oGetIEWindowFromTitle, sTitle, bCaseSensitive, bExact)
        If found Then Exit For
    Next

    'Check whether a window was found
    If Not found Then
        Set oGetIEWindowFromTitle = Nothing
    Else




        Do While oGetIEWindowFromTitle.Busy '----- this is what I have tried
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
        Loop


        Do While oGetIEWindowFromTitle.Busy = True Or oGetIEWindowFromTitle.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop '------ this is what I have tried




    End If

End Function
```

```
Private Function oGetIEWindowFromTitleHandler(win As Shdocvw.InternetExplorer, _
                                      sTitle As String, _
                                      bCaseSensitive As Boolean, _
                                      bExact As Boolean) As Boolean

    oGetIEWindowFromTitleHandler = False

    On Error GoTo handler
    'If the document is of type HTMLDocument, it is an IE window
    If TypeName(win.Document) = "HTMLDocument" Then
        'Check whether the title contains the passed title
        If bExact Then
            If (win.Document.Title = sTitle) Or ((Not bCaseSensitive) And (LCase(sTitle) = LCase(win.Document.Title))) Then oGetIEWindowFromTitleHandler = True
        Else
            If InStr(1, win.Document.Title, sTitle) Or ((Not bCaseSensitive) And (InStr(1, LCase(win.Document.Title), LCase(sTitle), vbTextCompare) <> 0)) Then oGetIEWindowFromTitleHandler = True
        End If
    End If
handler:
    'We assume here that if an error is raised it's because
    'the window is not of the correct type. Therefore we
    'simply ignore it and carry on.

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim w As Object, t

    t = Timer
    Set w = WaitForWindow("google.com", 10)

    If Not w Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "Found in " & Timer - t
    Else
        Debug.Print "Not found after " & Timer - t
    End If

End Sub

'Find (or wait for) an IE window with location
'   matching URL (using "Like" for matching)
'Try for maxWait seconds then give up
Function WaitForWindow(URL As String, maxWait As Long)
    Dim rv As Object, t
    t = Timer
    Do While Timer - t < maxWait
        Set rv = GetIEByUrl(URL)
        If Not rv Is Nothing Then Exit Do
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
    Loop
    Set WaitForWindow = rv
End Function

'Try to get an existing IE window based on URL match
Function GetIEByUrl(URL As String) As Object
    Dim o As Object, rv As Object
    For Each o In CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows
        If TypeName(o) = "IWebBrowser2" Then
            If o.Locationurl Like "*" & URL & "*" Then
                Set rv = o
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next o
    Set GetIEByUrl = rv
End Function
```

Comment: Nice approach there.